# Generate password protected PDF from base64 string or byte array and send as a attachment to email

Tags: java

- Generating pdf with base64 String which generated through jasper report,I can make password protected in jrxml as well but i have different requirement so i can't keep there.
  I want to make protected pdf while sending attachment only so i tried many possibilities like (pdf writer,streamer and all) but nothing worked.
  Below code i used to generate pdf as attachment , i want to make that attachment as password protected.*

  ```
  MimeMessage message = mailSenderImpl.createMimeMessage();
  MimeMessageHelper helper;
  helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
  helper.setFrom(CacheUtils.getConfig(ApplicationConstant.
  DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL));
  helper.setTo(request.getToEmail());
  helper.setSubject(request.getSendSubject());
  helper.setText("", request.getSendMessage());
  String sendAttachment = request.getSendAttachment();

  JSONObject jsonRec = new JSONObject(sendAttachment);
  JSONArray jArray = jsonRec.getJSONArray("Attachment");
  DataSource dataSource;
  String sAttachName;
  String sAttachBase64;
  JSONObject jsonRec = new JSONObject(sendAttachment);
  JSONArray jArray = jsonRec.getJSONArray("Attachment");
  DataSource dataSource;
  String sAttachName;
  String sAttachBase64;


  sAttachName = jArray.getJSONObject(i).has("AttachName") ?jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("AttachName") : null;
  sAttachBase64 = jArray.getJSONObject(i).has("AttachBase64") ? jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("AttachBase64") : null;

  dataSource = sAttachBase64 !=null ? new  
  ByteArrayDataSource(Base64.getDecoder().decode(sAttachBase64.getBytes()), "application/pdf") : null;

  helper.addAttachment(sAttachName, dataSource);
  ```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please can you share the code you have tried so far.

Comment: ammended question please check

Comment: Please format this illegible mess.

Answer (score 3):

The pdf writer class in the java is able to make encrypted pdf files. You can create with it. PDF Writer class provides encrypt with username, password and also encryption type, permission etc... You can find more detail on there: [PDF Writer Class](https://codesjava.com/itext-add-password-protection-to-pdf-in-java)

Comment: My code  will generate document with a dataSource object as attchment in the email itself.So if i use PDF writer, mail attached pdf is not generating with password protected.

Comment: If it  is auto-generated, you can use other class like [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org) or [iText](https://www.concretepage.com/itext/add-password-encrypt-decrypt-pdf-using-itext-in-java]) api's.  There is examples for them.

Comment: Using Itext only, PDF generation and attachment everything working fine but when i open an attachment in email, password protection is not happening. Moreover the link which you have given for itext is not working.Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for my fault. The link which last comment is there [iText Documentation](https://api.itextpdf.com/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/). You can find [iText Encryption](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/examples/itext-7/encrypting-decrypting-pdfs) and [iText Decryption](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/faq/technical-support/itext-7/how-decrypt-pdf-document-owner-password) details on the links.

Comment: i gone through the link, in all example they are doing operations on generated(Physical) pdf not with datasource object or byte array.

Answer (score 0):

```
byteStream = Base64.getDecoder().decode(sAttachBase64);
inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteStream); 
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
     baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
reader = new PdfReader(byteStream);
stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, baos);
stamper.setEncryption("test".getBytes(), "test".getBytes(),PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING, PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128 | PdfWriter.DO_NOT_ENCRYPT_METADATA);
stamper.close();
dataSource = new ByteArrayDataSource(baos.toByteArray(), "application/pdf");
```